# Return field where text was found in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, field, elasticsearch

I need help. I have these documents on elasticsearch 1.6

```
{
 "name":"Sam",
 "age":25,
 "description":"Something"
},
{
 "name":"Michael",
 "age":23,
 "description":"Something else"
}
```

with this query:

`GET /MyIndex/MyType/_search?q=Michael`

Elastic return this object:

```
{
 "name":"Michael",
 "age":23,
 "description":"Something else"
}
```

... That's right, but I want to get the exactly key where text "Michael" was found. Is that possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by key you mean the document ID.
When indexing the following documents:

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
     "name":"Sam",
     "age":25,
     "description":"Something"
}

PUT my_index/my_type/2
{
     "name":"Michael",
     "age":23,
     "description":"Something else"
}
```

And searching for:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search?q=Michael
```

You'll get the following response:

```
{
   "took": 8,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.15342641,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.15342641,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Michael",
               "age": 23,
               "description": "Something else"
            }
         }
     ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, the hits array contains an object for each search hit.
The key for Michael in this case is "_id": "2" which its his document id.

Hope it helps.